# using Keycloak for Customer Register

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I am building a Website where a user can later on register to use some features. I wanted to use Java-Spring boot for Registration and Login now I learned about Keycloak for authorization, I searched the web a bit but could not find anything which helped me in that matter.

So my Question is it possible to use keycloak as a registration/Login form? As far as I know keycloak is used company intern to give the employees users to different services or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak is a full solution for authentication and authorization. You can register users, login users, change privileges and so on. What I recommend is to use their official [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) to spin up a local instance, and have a look what the admin console offers.

There are too many features to list in an answer here, but I recommend this [getting started](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/#overview) guide, to maybe give you a better understanding of the basics.

In addition, there is a good [Spring Boot integration](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-spring-boot-starter) available, as well as numerous adapters for the countless front-end frameworks.